# $.getJSON() is not getting triggerd

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, getjson

For some odd reason my .getJSON() function isn't working. It is not giving me any error messages neither.

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Hello from riskanalysis.delete.js");

    var categoryTd = $('#categoryId');
    var categoryText = categoryTd.text();
    var categoryInt = parseInt(categoryText);


    console.log(categoryInt);
    console.log(categoryText);


    console.log("Hello before");
    $.getJSON("/riskanalysis/getCategoryNameById?categoryId=" + categoryInt)
            .done(function (categoryName) {
                // On success
                console.log("Category name is: " + categoryName);
                categoryTd.text(categoryName); 
            }).fail(function (e) { console.log(e); });

    console.log("Hello");
    console.log("Hello after");
});
```

My controller code:

```
        [Route("riskanalysis/getCategoryNameById")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetCategoryNameById(int categoryId)
        {
            return _manager.GetCategoryNameById(categoryId);
        }
```

My manager code:

```
        public string GetCategoryNameById(int categoryId)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new Entities.DanoneRiskanalysisContext())
            {
                Entities.Category entitiy = dbContext.Category
                .Where(c => c.Id.Equals(categoryId))
                .FirstOrDefault();
                if (entitiy != null)
                {
                    return entitiy.ListCategories;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

My manager interface code:

```
string GetCategoryNameById(int categoryId);
```

My .cshtml code:

```
  <tr>
     <td>Category</td>
     <td id="categoryId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.categoryId)</td>
  </tr>
```

Added a .fail function, this is the result:

[image]

Added `.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) { var err = textStatus + ", " + error; console.log( "Request Failed: " + err ); });`

Result: Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Does anyone have an idea why this function isn't working?

Thanks already!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in console apart from Hello messages? If yes, please post those errors.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the console apart the "Hello messages".

Comment: Catch the error after done with `fail` i.e `fail(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  })`

Comment: Since you are seeing only Hello messages, not "Category Name" message which is in success function, please write a .fail function to know the exact error information. My guess is, it may not be able to resolve url - like for e.g., when categoryInt is null or undefined and MVC won't  be find any endpoint (riskanalysis/getCategoryNameById) which  takes null argument. To isolate the issue, you can hardcode some value for categoryInt and see if that is working or not. Or may be categoryInt is assigned with 0.

Comment: I recommend setting a breakpoint on your controller code to see if the categoryId is even getting sent over the wire.

Comment: I am getting a status code of 200 so it should be ok? But still it isn't working, anyone got an idea why this is?

Comment: Added a .fail and posted the error message i got from it. @sam

Comment: Could you please modify your fail function as follows: `.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});`

Comment: I just did that and the result is this: Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0 , i really dont understand what is happening. @sam

Comment: Huh, the response from your controller action is a string as opposed to json format. Try to return JsonResult from MVC action. it should work. But glad that you figured it out yourself via ajax.  I am positive that if you specify application/json as dataType, then ajax will also throw the error. Are you specifying application/json in ajax call by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `$.getJSON()` to `$.ajax` fixed my issue!

Comment: Probably the backend is not returning a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your controller action to return json response as you are using .getJson on client side.

```
[Route("riskanalysis/getCategoryNameById")]
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetCategoryNameById(int categoryId)
{
    return Json(_manager.GetCategoryNameById(categoryId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```